# Android Data binding Error:Could not find com.android.databindig:databinder:1.0.-rc1

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, gradle

I have been trying for hours now to enable data binding in Android. Here is my gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'


        classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ts.kiosk.app.checkout"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.0.2.258"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'

    compile project(':asterixmodule')
    compile project(':servicemodule')
    compile project(':sdfclient')

    // Robolectric
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3' // fixes issue on linux/mac
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.databindig:databinder:1.0.-rc1   .
```

I have also read similar posts on SO stating that you also have to add:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'
```

but my gradle is 2.4 so I'm thinking I don't need that and of course if I do add that statement, gradle cannot find that version of gradle  (1.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to version 2.0 of Android Studio and the gradle build issue went away

Answer (score 0):

remove

`classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0"`

Starting with android gradle plugin `1.5.0`, all you need is

`android {
    dataBinding.enabled = true
}`

Comment: Yeah I had tried that too and I get:                                                                     Error:(63, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'dataBinding()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'Checkout' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: does not sound like you are using android gradle plugin 1.5

Comment: Yep you are right, I was not. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.  Now I have another data binding build issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582464/data-binding-compiler-error-cannot-resolve-type-for-safevarargs

Answer (score 0):

check your gradle version, i resolved it by upgrading :

previously :

`classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0"`

I updated to :

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0"
```

Or 1.5.0 and newer.