# Cannot Get a simple TextView to work with Android Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding

OK, I finally have my Android Data Binding code compiling. Now, It does not work as I expect. When I call `setCurrentShopperInfo()` from my `Activity`, My `TextView`(s) do not update with the `String`s values I'm setting.

**NOTE:** I also tried this with using `ObservableField`(s), same result.

There *HAS* to be something I'm not understanding here:

**LAYOUT:**

```
<data>
        <variable name="currentShopperViewModel" type="ts.kiosk.app.checkout.viewmodels.CurrentShopperViewModel" />
        <import type="android.view.View" />
    </data>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

             <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/checkout_titlebar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/app_header_height"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@color/header_bkgrd">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_ts_logo"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/app_icon_width"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_icon_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_icon_margin"
                    android:src="@drawable/touchsides_logo_notext"/>
                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/text_appname"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/title_checkout"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_ts_logo"
                     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                     style="@style/screenTitle"/>

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:visibility="visible"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:orientation="horizontal"
                     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_appname"
                     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_settings_menu"
                     android:paddingRight="20dip"
                     android:paddingLeft="20dip"
                     android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                     <TextView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:text="@{currentShopperViewModel.textShopperInfoName}"
                         style="@style/previous_transaction_titlebar"></TextView>
                     <TextView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:text="@{currentShopperViewModel.textShopperInfoCashback}"
                         style="@style/previous_transaction_titlebar_cashback"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"></TextView>
                     <TextView
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:text="@{currentShopperViewModel.textShopperInfoPoints}"
                         style="@style/previous_transaction_titlebar_points"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"></TextView>
                 </LinearLayout>
```

**ACTIVITY:**

```
mCurentShopperViewModel = new CurrentShopperViewModel(this);
        final ActivityCheckoutNewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_checkout_new);
        binding.setCurrentShopperViewModel(mCurentShopperViewModel);
```

VIEW MODEL:

```
public class CurrentShopperViewModel extends BaseObservable{

    Context mCtx;

    //public ObservableBoolean showShopperInfo = new ObservableBoolean();


    private String textShopperInfoName;
    private String textShopperInfoCashback;
    private String textShopperInfoPoints;


    @Bindable
    public String getTextShopperInfoName() {
        return this.textShopperInfoName;
    }
    @Bindable
    public String getTextShopperInfoCashback() {
        return this.textShopperInfoCashback;
    }
    @Bindable
    public String getTextShopperInfoPoints() {
        return this.textShopperInfoPoints;
    }


    public void setTextShopperInfoName(String name) {
        this.textShopperInfoName = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.textShopperInfoName);
    }
    public void setTextShopperInfoCashback(String cashback) {
        this.textShopperInfoCashback = cashback;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.textShopperInfoCashback);
    }
    public void setTextShopperInfoPoints(String points) {
        this.textShopperInfoPoints = points;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.textShopperInfoPoints);
    }


    public CurrentShopperViewModel(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }


    public void  setCurrentShopperInfo(CardStructure cardStructure ) {

        //show(true);

        int[] card = CardUtil.getInstance().getBalance(cardStructure);

        setTextShopperInfoName( String.format( "%s %s", mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.item_wallet_desposit) , Formatter.formatCurrency(CheckoutApplication.LOCALE,card[0]) ) );
        setTextShopperInfoCashback(  String.format( "%s %s", mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.item_wallet_desposit) , Formatter.formatCurrency(CheckoutApplication.LOCALE,card[0]) )  );
        setTextShopperInfoPoints ( String.format( "%s %s",  mCtx.getResources().getString(R.string.item_loyalty_points),card[1] ) );
    }
```

GRADLE:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
    }
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'


repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ts.kiosk.app.checkout"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.0.2.258"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }


    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    //compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'

    // Robolectric
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3' // fixes issue on linux/mac
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'

    compile project(':asterixmodule')
    compile project(':servicemodule')
    compile project(':sdfclient')


}

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.xml'
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

Not sure what what would be significant here, but I see this after I call `setCurrentShopperInfo()` from my `Activity`:

```
04-12 21:31:30.252 866-866/ts.kiosk.app.checkout E/java.lang.StackTraceElement: InterfaceError
```

NOTIFY PROPERTY CHANGED Debugging

I stepped into the notifyPropertyChanged() method and mCallbacks size is 0 --- is that correct?

```
/**
     * Notifies listeners that a specific property has changed. The getter for the property
     * that changes should be marked with {@link Bindable} to generate a field in
     * <code>BR</code> to be used as <code>fieldId</code>.
     *
     * @param fieldId The generated BR id for the Bindable field.
     */
    public void notifyPropertyChanged(int fieldId) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, fieldId, null);
        }
    }
```

I also tried the ObservableField way of setting data binding where ultimately this is called:

```
public synchronized void notifyChange() {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, 0, null);
        }
    }
```

and mCallbacks is again null and I'm thinking that is an issue but don't know how to debug it.

Comment: Might be worth including gradle configuration too.

Comment: PLease post your log cat

Comment: anyone have any clues? is there any possible way to debug this?

Comment: Nothing obvious during a first look from me.

Comment: Man, I have tried everything, can't get it to work.

Comment: if the observers are empty, CurrentShopperViewModel instance you are updating is not the CurrentShopperViewModel instance you've assigned to the binding class. If you suspect observability, you can try invalidateAll after setting to see what happens.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#invalidateAll()

Comment: @Yigit , I tried:  mCurentShopperViewModel.setCurrentShopperInfo(structure);
        mBinding.invalidateAll();                                                                                            No difference.                                                                                                           Not sure how CurrentShopperViewModel  is not the CurrentShopperViewModel instance I've assigned to the binding class, mCurentShopperViewModel is a member variable.

Comment: @Yigit   Also, I tried setting the values of the TextViews with findViewById, (just to make sure nothing is being hidden) and that works fine.

Comment: @Yigit  I tried also using this way:    ObservableField<String> textShopperInfoName = new ObservableField<String>();   THEN populating this way:   this.textShopperInfoName.set("test")......ultimately this is called:   public synchronized void notifyChange() {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.notifyCallbacks(this, 0, null);
        }
    }                                                                                                                      mCallBacks is always null---- it should not be , correct?

Comment: I also tried:   boolean pending = mBinding.hasPendingBindings();   mBinding.getData().setCurrentShopperInfo(structure);       pending = true

Comment: the errors your are reporting are really weird, we've not seen any bugs like this. Can you create a sample application and report a bug with it so that we can take a look at it?

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that in OnCreate() I was calling setContentView() twice ...once for the data binding and then again the old way (which apparently overwrote the data binding):

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity)

//other code here

setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```

Comment: I had the same problem but in a Fragment. I was inflating layout "normally" AND with databinding: `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
MyFragmentBinding binding = MyFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);`